# iOS swift BLE read multiple characteristics

Tags: ios, swift, uuid, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to design an app that read several temperatures. Is it true that one characteristic UUID can only handle 1 value? If so, how can I read multiple values?(For instance, temperature 1, temperature 2, temperature 3...) Do I need to declare multiple characteristic UUIDs myself? But if I only declare those in my app, how would the peripheral know what UUID corresponds to what value then? Most of the example only read one value (temperature, heart rate,etc)

Comment: "I'm new to apple,", "There's no one in the company know iOS", "I'm just an intern"... Nothing personal, but we don't care. What are you asking?

Comment: It is edited, sorry. So do you know the answer?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: Don't waste your time here then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get different values from the same characteristic. For that, you may have to write different values to the write characteristic. For example, say your write characteristic is **A** and your read characteristic **B**.

You can write a value to **A** like this

```
[self.discoveredPeripheral writeValue:data
                    forCharacteristic:characteristic
                                 type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

where data varies as per the request that you would like to make.

For your read characteristic **B**, the indication property should be set to YES as follows in the **didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService** delegate callback

```
if (c.properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate) {
    [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:c];
}
```

Now whenever you write a value to **A**, you will get a callback on the delegate method **didUpdateValueForCharacteristic**. You will have to handle the response properly.

Of course, for all of this to work, your ble device should be programmed accordingly.

Note that the code is written in Objective-C

Comment: Thank you. The problem was solved using the same idea as you said.

Comment: If it was helpful or is the solution to your problem, please mark it as accepted. It would be helpful to others if anyone else encounters such an issue in future.